# Facebook photo.addtag give me an error "Invalid photo tag subject"

Tags: facebook, api, tags, photo

I've a new problem with photo tagging in facebook rest api...
I'm using photo.addTag with the correct parameter but the response give me an error "Invalid photo tag subject"

How can i fix it? 
Thanks

https://api.facebook.com/method/photos.addTag?pid=100001615002070_596708&tag_uid= FRIEND_UID&x=0&y=0&owner_uid= OWNER_UID&access_token=XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX&format=json

Comment: Also new graph api TAG function give me that error "(#322) Invalid photo tag subject".... What's the problem? :( For me all parameters are ok... and some months ago it worked fine

Answer (score 0):

the new graph api has a different parameter, you have to change "tag_uid" to "to", as described here:
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/photo/

(see the section about tags)

can you present the full code of your call to the graph api? would be easier to help you then.